# Transparent rounded corners in PHP

Tags: php, png, transparent, rounded-corners

Is it possible to create transparent corners for an image on fly with PHP? I think that it would be possible, but I am missing a function that would preserve alpha values when you copy your image.

My idea was to create an image of same width and height, then apply transparent corners, but then I need to preserve the alpha channel and just copy image on that mask, leaving transparent still transparent, but colors changed to copied image (or vice versa, put mask on image).

Is it possible to do that and what are commands for that if there are any?

Update: Thanks for helping with this. It was some time ago, and I forgot but if anybody cross this question to find a solution just visit this one: http://www.pc-siete.g6.cz/galery.html . I made functions for gradient, radial gradient and also those rounded corners so feel free to use :) . I'm not really using it on my webstie, but it's good to have them prepared.

For some reason the downloaded file had just ad in it. Now it's stored inside zip and downloads properly.

Comment: Create an arc using [imagearc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagearc.php). See the example, it's rounded. :-)

Comment: uhm.. not quite what I was looking for. I don't want to draw circles :D I need to cut corners of some omage into rounded ones, and leave background transparent ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built-in function to do this. However you can create one yourself along these lines:

```
function imageapplyroundedcorners(&$img,$radius) {
    // for each corner
        // loop through pixels between corner and (corner +- radius)
            // if distance between pixel and radius > radius, make transparent
            // elseif distance > radius-1 make partially transparent (for antialiasing)
}
```

Comment: that could work actually, but it's kind of bruteforce solution.. anyway if nothing else emerge I'll try that one ;)

Comment: I have an (unfortunate) tendancy to go with brute-force solutions first, then work out the easy way XD So yeah, this'll work (and I might write the code for it soon to use myself), but there's a fair chance a more efficient solution exists (but does it have antialiasing?)

Comment: I doubt that I am now looking on some ImageMagick functions mentioned down there but all seems to be experimental, not documented and people having trouble with them :/ Looks like until we have decent tools, we need to go bruteforce ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just created this function using ImageMagick in PHP which does exactly what I wanted. You need to set the `TEMP_DIR` constant and have the `convert` executable on your execution path.

```
function png_corners($image, $r = 12)
{
    //Dump out the image as a PNG file.
    $tmp_file = tempnam(TEMP_DIR, "image") . ".png";
    imagepng($image, $tmp_file);

    //Final image file.
    $tmp_out_file = tempnam(TEMP_DIR, "out") . ".png";

    $x = imagesx($image);
    $y = imagesy($image);

    $cmd = "convert -size {$x}x{$y} xc:none -fill white -draw 'roundRectangle 0,0, {$x} ,{$y}, {$r}, {$r}' {$tmp_file} -compose SrcIn -composite {$tmp_out_file}";
    exec($cmd);

    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    $contents = file_get_contents($tmp_out_file);
    echo $contents;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: well this one was pretty old but nwm maybe someone looking for imagick one will find what he need..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel use the [PHP thumbnailer](http://www.phpcontext.com/thumbnailer/demo) which will make everything for you:

```
require 'Thumbnailer.php';

$th=new Thumbnailer("photo.jpg");
$th->thumbFixed(120,90)->round()->save("thumb.jpg");
```

Comment: 1. long ago answered  2. If someone wouldn't "reinvent" which in fact is just understanding how to do something, when the old generation dies there wouldn't be anyone to advance and THAT would be real reinventing..

Answer (score -1):

See the [ImageMagick reference](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php). Yes, everything you describe is possible, all the tools are there.